# Extract numbers from a string in PHP with Regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I try to get numbers only from a string by using `preg_replace`.

From this string:

```
\n
                \t\n
                        \n
                                4 290 &euro;\n
                                \n
                            \n
                        \n
                    \n
```

I've tried following patterns:

- `(.*|\n)(\d+[[:blank:]]\d+)(.+|\n)`
- `preg_replace('/(.*|\n)(\d+[[:blank:]]\d+)(.+|\n)/', '$2', $string);`
- `preg_replace('/(\d+ \d+)/', '$1', $string);`

I want to ouput `4290`. None of the code above worked for me.

thanks for tips

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$only_digits = preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $string);
```

Upper `\D` - the opposite of `\d` - matches *non-digits*.

[Demo (regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/IAkEj6/1)